# What is the difference between AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer and AuthenticationTypes.Secure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I read about the two types in MSDN :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Yet, I'm not completly sure I understand the difference.

Please tell me if I understand correctly,

> AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer is used to secure the packets
>   sent in via the ldap communication.
>
> AuthenticationTypes.Secure is used to secure the connection, i.e.
>   prevent from attacker to use an ldap query without authentication.

Thank you

Comment: One says it requires SSL. One says it requires authentication, i.e. (normally) a username and password. Much like it says in the first table of the linked article.

Comment: @J. Steen Is it logical to use only AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer without AuthenticationTypes.Secure?

Comment: In this context? No clue. In general? Sure. You can visit an https-secured webpage without providing NTLM authentication credentials, after all. =)

Comment: Don't take my comment as definitive answer, though. There's no reason not to secure the connection, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer uses SSL which uses the certificate to authenticate and the traffic is encrypted. So by AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer it's already "secured".

For AuthenticationTypes.Secure, it uses the NTLM or Kerberos to authenticate (so the passwords are encrypted). But other traffic (like what objects are requested, their attribute names and values) are not encrypted. To encrypt, need to specify the also Sealing flag (together with Secure). But this requires Kerberos.

The 2 flags are referring to different way to secure the connection, so won't be used together normally (I never tried putting them together).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer together with @J. Steen comments helped me to understand much better the difference between the two types.